# checkbox value not executed in condition

Tags: java, android, xml

i am newbee in andriod,i am trying to print the `selected checkbox` value in toast msg,but the problem is `if condition` is not executed, but i give the condition `pizza.isSelected()` to execute the if loop  , My Expected output is `selected item pizza price is 100`,but i got `selected item 0`

[image]

```
  My MainActivity.java is

package com.example.uicheckbox;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public CheckBox pizza,coffee,burger;
public Button buttonsubmit;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
buttonClick();
}
public void buttonClick() {
pizza=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
coffee=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
burger=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
buttonsubmit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
buttonsubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
builder.append("Selected Items");
int totalamount =0;
if(pizza.isSelected())
{
System.out.println("pizza");
totalamount+= 100;
builder.append("Pizza price is");
}
if(coffee.isSelected())
{
System.out.println("coffee");
totalamount+= 70;
builder.append("Cofee price is");
}
if(burger.isSelected())
{
System.out.println("burger");
totalamount+= 120;
builder.append("Burger price is");
}
builder.append(totalamount);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),builder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});
}
}
```

and my xml file for this activity is

```
activity_main.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/menu1" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:text="@string/menu2" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:text="@string/menu3" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="87dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:text="@string/order" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
if (pizza.isChecked()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @electtrofant thanks aloat,now App work successfully,and i need one more help,how to print more than two selected box total amount eg:pizza price 100 , coffee price 70 but i need to define the toast outside the if condition.

Comment: Actually that should work fine with your code. You built the string in the if statements and show the toast afterward.

Answer (score 1):

for checkboxes it is ischecked not isselected